# View not found error when enabling error pages in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config, custom-error-pages

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have the `/errors/error.html` page as a general error page and a second `/errors/error404.aspx` that handles the 404 errors.

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/errors/error.html">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/errors/error404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Also, I have in my `Global.asax` file a general handler that logs all uncaught exceptions for logging purposes.

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    Common.Core.LogError(ex); // Saving exception details in the database
}
```

The above setup works well except for when I have a general error (e.g. a 500 error) the `Application_Error` logs this error below:

> The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/app/Error.aspx
>   ~/Views/app/Error.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
>   ~/Views/app/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/app/Error.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
>  
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml

The Exception from the actual error is not logged at all.

How can I avoid this error?

P.S. For anyone who might ask, I tried to put my error pages as views inside a controller but also I couldn't make it work with the `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to handle errors in a non-ASP.NET MVC way, in an ASP.NET MVC project. To resolve your issue, you could comment the line `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` in the FilterConfig.cs file. See the snippet below.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that made it work! Yes, I realized that I was a bit away from the MVC way, but the MVC way seemed a bit of overkill at the time.